# Slider display items from list instead of numerical values in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

As I am quite new to Flutter I can't seem to figure this out on my own. I am wondering if it's possible to display strings from a list instead of the numbers in a Slider? F.ex. If Slider number = 1, display label "Age 1". It seems that I am always coming back to carousels, but they don't act/look like what I want. At the moment I have a dropdownbutton with 18 items, and it's a bit disorganized/ugly displaying it in that manner. It also follows a linear path from Newborn to 12 years.

I don't have any code on this, as all attempts I've made hasn't lead me anywhere. Thus I am asking if anyone knows a way to do this, tips or a solution. All help is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
  double _currentSliderValue = 0;

 var result =['one','two','three'];
```

and then:

```
  Slider(
    value: _currentSliderValue,
    min: 0,
    max: 2,
    divisions:2,
    label: result[_currentSliderValue.toInt()],
    onChanged: (double value) {
      setState(() {
        _currentSliderValue = value;
      });
    },
  )
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly, and I was able to modify it to fit my needs! I made a string retrieve the state of the slider: stringValueSlider = result[_currentSliderValue.toInt()]; and used f.ex. Text(stringValueSlider == '1 year') ? 'somethingsomething' : '');

Thank you!